# Insertar y Buscar en campo Datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy tratando de insertar una fecha con milisegundos, pero no consigo realizarlo.
La fecha en bash tiene el siguiente formato:

```
"%d%m%Y%H%M%S%2N"
```

Mientras que en BBDD me aparece lo siguiente:

```
MariaDB [db]> INSERT INTO access_wifi(DATA) VALUES ('0511201813450367');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [db]> select * from access_wifi;
+----+------------------------+
| id | DATA                   |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.00 |
|  2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.00 |
|  3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.00 |
+----+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Que comando debería de usar para insertar y para realizar la búsqueda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que dices, estás queriendo insertar una cadena con cierto formato en la columna `DATA` que parece ser algún tipo de `datetime`, en cuyo caso, el problema que tienes es que debería "interpretar" la cadena en un `datetime` antes de insertar el valor. Podemos usar [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
INSERT INTO access_wifi(DATA) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('0511201813450367', '%d%m%Y%H%i%s%f'))
```

Luego, el otro problema es ver la fecha completa, para lo que puedes hacer uso de [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(DATA, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s:%f')
        FROM access_wifi
```

puedes consultar la documentación completa de la cadena de formato en los enlaces a las funciones, en tu caso estamos usando

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════════════╗
║ %d ║ Day of the month, numeric (00..31) ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════╣
║ %f ║ Microseconds (000000..999999)      ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════╣
║ %H ║ Hour (00..23)                      ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════╣
║ %i ║ Minutes, numeric (00..59)          ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════╣
║ %m ║ Month, numeric (00..12)            ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════╣
║ %Y ║ Year, numeric, four digits         ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════╣
║ %s ║ Seconds (00..59)                   ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Nota: La columna debería ser un `datetime` (por ej. `datetimr(3)`) con la precisión suficiente para albergar los milisegundos que estas queriendo insertar

Comment: gracias @Patricio Moracho !